# In Python, how to multiply each element in a multidimensional list by a number?

Tags: python, list

I have a multidimensional list of floats (or ints, I think it doesn't matter in our case), say, a list named lst = [[1,2],[1,1],[4,5]]. The dimension of the list is not specified: it doesn't have to be 2. lst could also be a 3-dimensional list, which is something like [[[1,2],[1,1],[4,5]],[[1,2],[1,1],[4,5]]]. I want to multiply each number in lst by a given number, say, 2.

If lst is one-dimensional, one way to do this is to define lst2 = [i*2 for i in lst]. However, this doesn't work for a high dimensional list. One could also use loops to do this element by element, but since the dimension of lst is not specified, the number of loops needed is unknown.

Does anyone have some idea how to do this neatly?

Comment: "Neatly" is subjective. `l = (2*np.array(l)).tolist()` is a reasonable suggestion if you can accept a dependency.

Comment: @erip Thank you for your comment. The solution works well. I thought that only "rectangular" lists (such that the lengths of all sublists are equal) could be converted to NumPy arrays. In fact, it also works for lists like [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]].

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion for the task, e.g.:

```py
lst = [[[1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 5]], [[1, 2], [1, 1], [4, 5]]]

def multiply(obj, number):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [multiply(v, number) for v in obj]
    else:
        return obj * number

new_lst = multiply(lst, 2)
print(new_lst)
```

Prints:

```
[[[2, 4], [2, 2], [8, 10]], [[2, 4], [2, 2], [8, 10]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more generally useful, you could make this util that works with any function:

```
def nested_map(func, obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, list):
        return func(obj)
    return [nested_map(func, x) for x in obj]


nested_map(lambda n: 2*n, lst)
# [[[2, 4], [2, 2], [8, 10]], [[2, 4], [2, 2], [8, 10]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves the problem well and shows a general way to deal with such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a general function to make this work between nested lists of any dimensions:

```
def broadcast(a,b,oper):
    match = isinstance(a,list),isinstance(b,list)
    if match == (False,False): return oper(a,b)
    if match == (True,False):  return [broadcast(i,b,oper) for i in a]
    if match == (False,True):  return [broadcast(a,i,oper) for i in b]
    a = a + a[-1:]*(len(b)-len(a))
    b = b + b[-1:]*(len(a)-len(b))
    return [broadcast(i,j,oper) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

outputs:

```
A = [ [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9] ]
B = [ [10,20,30] ]
C = [100,200,300]

mult = lambda a,b: a*b
add  = lambda a,b: a+b

print(*broadcast(A,10,mult),sep="\n")
[10, 20, 30]
[40, 50, 60]
[70, 80, 90]

print(*broadcast(A,B,add),sep="\n")
[11, 22, 33]
[14, 25, 36]
[17, 28, 39]

print(*broadcast(A,C,add),sep="\n")
[101, 102, 103]
[204, 205, 206]
[307, 308, 309]

print(*broadcast(B,C,add),sep="\n")
[110, 120, 130]
[210, 220, 230]
[310, 320, 330]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is indeed a nice method to solve the problem in a general way.